# CSS/PHP - Using Different CSS for each PHP string

Tags: php, html, css

I posted my original issue a while ago, back here:

[CSS/PHP - Overlaying an Image with Hover and If Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317114/css-php-overlaying-an-image-with-hover-and-if-statements)

Since then, I've fixed my main issue, and am now left with one more.
The code which returns the server looks like this:

```
<?php 
  foreach($servers as $server): 

  $stats = \Minecraft\Stats::retrieve(new \Minecraft\Server($server)); 
?>
<center>
  <pre>
    <div class="server">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="<?php echo($stats->is_online) ? 'online' : 'offline'; ?>"></div>
      <div class="numbers"><?php printf('%u/%u', $stats->online_players, $stats->max_players); ?></div>         
    </div>
  </pre>
</center>
```

As you can see, all of these servers are under one CSS "server" class. This is posing problems, as I need each server returned to have different images.

Here is the CSS for the server class:

```
.server {
    background: url('img/servers/hg.png') center no-repeat;
    width:  330px;
    height: 280px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
 }
.server:hover { 
    background: url('img/servers/hg-hover.png') center no-repeat;
 }
```

How can I select the individual servers, or make a list of CSS to be executed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
.server:nth-child(1) {
    background: url('img/servers/hg1.png') center no-repeat;
}
.server:nth-child(2) {
    background: url('img/servers/hg2.png') center no-repeat;
}
.server:nth-child(3) {
    background: url('img/servers/hg3.png') center no-repeat;
}
...
```

Comment: Doing this affected all of the returned servers.
It is however, what I am looking for. Something similar.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Is there still a problem?

Comment: Yes, there are multiple servers. This changed all of their images, instead of just one.

Comment: But... that's what you asked for. Maybe you should clarify in your question above exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add specific css for every server, you can add an extra class:

```
<div class="server background_image_class_<?php echo $server->ID; ?>">
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^ some variable that uniquely identifies the server.
```

If you have the images stored in the same database as the server information, you could also use inline css:

```
<div class="server" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $server->backgroundImage; ?>);">
```

**Edit:** You could remove all non-word characters from the server url and use that as a class name:

```
<div class="server <?php echo  preg_replace("/[^\w]/", "", $server); ?>">
```

Now you can use the modified server name in your css:

```
.server {
  // general styles
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  // etc.
}
.hg1playminezoneco {
  // image background form this specific server
  background-image: url(/path/to/hg1playminezoneco.png);
}
.hg1playminezoneco:hover {
  // image background form this specific server on hover
  background-image: url(/path/to/hg1playminezoneco-hover.png);
}
.pvpplayminezoneco {
  background-image: url(/path/to/pvpplayminezoneco.png);
}
.pvpplayminezoneco:hover {
  background-image: url(/path/to/pvpplayminezoneco-hover.png);
}
// etc.
```

Comment: How should I add ID's to the servers which are listed in an array:
http://pastie.org/private/lscbdr7ol4uyvbl8rcgeta

Comment: @LegacyP7 You would need to make sure that all characters are allowed as valid class name characters. Perhaps it would be easier to pick a (unique) property from the `$stats` object.

Comment: The $stats object is a separate document. Could you elaborate on "all characters are allowed as valid class name characters"?.
Thanks.

Comment: @LegacyP7 Well, for example dots are not allowed in class names, so you can't just use the server name as a class name. See here what is allowed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names

Comment: @LegacyP7 I have added an example with classes where all non-word characters are removed from the server url and the result is used as the class name.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the image specific CSS, e.g. background from the server class.
Assign the specific CSS to the images' ID.

Comment: The server's aren't ID'd. They are just in an array like this:

    $servers = array(
 "hg1.play-minezone.co",
 "pvp.play-minezone.co",
 "skywars.play-minezone.co",
 "dvz.play-minezone.co",
 "volaxia.play-minezone.co"
    );